# How to make search bar that search in different column

Tags: html, jquery, sql, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I trying to make search bar that search in different column I have an property table where I want to search the data with different things like I want to search data with price range an also I want to search data  with area range. I make this in asp.net core mvc. I want to make search look like that https://www.zameen.com/

My View:

```
@model IEnumerable<eHouse.Models.RentModel>

 <form>
                    <div class="wrap">
                        <div class="search">
                            <input type="text" class="searchTerm" style="width: 700px; color:#000000; text-align: left;" placeholder="Search Houses" onclick="filterfunction()">
                            <button type="submit" class="searchButton" >
                                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>

                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div id="filter">
                        <select>
                            <option value="Kanal">Kanal</option>
                            <option value="Marla">Marla</option>
                            <option value="Square Feet">Square Feet</option>
                            <option value="Square Meter">Square Meter</option>
                            <option value="Square Yards">Square Yards</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="area" />
                        <input type="text" placeholder="price" />

                    </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </form>
```

Kindly also tell me that how can I bind data with this to display in this div.

```
<div class="property_information" >

           @foreach (var item in Model)
           {
                <div class="home-info">
                    <span id="houseid">
                          
                    </span>
                  
                    <a href="#" class="home-images">
                        <img src="@item.pic1" />
                    </a>
                    <div class="home-data">
                        <div class="home-name">
                            <p>@item.tittle</p>
                        </div>
                       
                        <div class="price">
                            <p>@item.price</p>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="features">
                            <span>
                               @item.bedroom
                            </span>
                            <span>
                                 @item.bathroom
                            </span>
                            <span>
                                2
                            </span>
                        </div>
                       
                        <div class="desc">
                            @item.descrip
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact-save">
                            <a href="#" class="phone_number" id="favorite" onclick="Fav(this)" data-id="@item.id" >
                                <i class="fas fa-heart" style=" color: white;"></i>
                            </a>
                        
                            <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">
                            <a href="tel:+928754756478" class="phone_number" onclick="call()">
                            </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="popupmsg" onclick="myFunctionmsg()">
                               <a href="#" class="phone_number open_message" onclick="msg()">
                               </a>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#" class="phone_number" onclick="del(this)" data-id="@item.id">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"  style=" color: white;"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
    </div>
```

My Controller:

```
public IActionResult Rent(int PageNumber = 1)
{
    var data = rdb.GetDataHouse();
    var datas = rdb.GetDataHouse();
          
    ViewBag.Data = datas.ToList().Take(6);
          
    ViewBag.Totalpages = Math.Ceiling(data.Count()/6.0);

    data = data.Skip((PageNumber - 1) * 6).Take(6).ToList();

    return View(data);
}
```

Comment: you can pass the filtering criteria into your controller as a parameter and use `Where` on that `data`..

Comment: any example to sow it really helps me

Answer (score 1):

try using tables and import jquery data tables library

```
<table id="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>col 1</th>
                <th>col 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>data 1</td>
                <td>data 2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
        $('#table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ...rest
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: i have cards to display the data

Comment: https://isotope.metafizzy.co/ or try this library